# How to work with the mode of a probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

How do you work with a probability mass function in determining stuff related to the mode.

Here's the question I have

$P(X=x) = {\theta^n}{{n}\choose{x}}({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})^x, x = 0,1,2,...,n$

$0,$  otherwise

Show that the mode of $X$, $x^*$, is such that $n(1-\theta) - \theta \leq x^* \leq n(1-\theta) - \theta + 1$

Hint: The mode of a discrete random variable $X$ is that real value $x^*$ such that $P(X=x^*) \geq P(X=x)$ for all $x \in R$.

So I realize that I need to find $P(X=x)$ that gives the greatest number but how I do that efficiently is what I'm confused about.

Edit. Sorry. I forgot to add that random variable $X$ denotes the number of heads a coin comes up tails when tossed $n$ times. For each toss, the coin will appear heads with probability $\theta$

Here's my best attempt at answering the question.

Let $R = \frac{P(X = k + 1)}{P(X = k)} = \frac{{\theta}^n {{n} \choose {k+1}} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})^{k+1}}{{\theta}^n {{n} \choose {k}} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})^{k}} = \frac{{n} \choose {k+1}}{{n} \choose {k}}(\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}) = \frac{{n!}{(n-k)!}{k!}}{{n!}{{(n-k-1)!}}{(k+1)!}} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}}) = \frac{{(n-k)}{(n-k-1)!}{k!}}{{(n-k-1)!}{(k+1)}{k!}} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}}) = \frac{n-k}{k+1} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})$

when $k=0$

$R = n ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})$

when $k=1$

$R = \frac{n-1}{2} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})$

when $k=2$

$R = \frac{n-2}{3} ({\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}})$

and so on...

$\frac{n-(k+1)}{(k+1)+1} > \frac{n-k}{k+1}$ if the function is increasing

$\frac{n-k-1}{k+2} > \frac{n-k}{k+1}$

$(k+1)(n-k+1) > (n-k)(k+2)$

$nk - k^2 + k + n - k + 1 > nk + 2n - k^2 -2k$

$n<2k+1$

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ that $P(x)$ is as you have written it and not $$P(X=x) = {\theta^n}{{n}\choose{x}}\left(\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}\right)^x, x = 0,1,2,...,n ?? $$ If you are indeed sure that what you have written is correct, first try and prove that the function you have is indeed a probability mass function. In particular, tell us all what $\binom{1-\theta}{\theta}^x$ is when $\theta$ is not an integer.

Comment: Yes. It was meant to be $(\frac{1-\theta}{\theta})^x$. Sorry

Comment: Your calculations are incorrect. The denominator is not a quadratic function of $k$ as you have found.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. I fixed that now

Comment: Last and absolutely final hint: For $a, b > 0$, $\frac ab > 1$ if and only if $a > b$. Now set $a = (n-k)\theta, b = (k+1)\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $X \sim Bin(n, 1-\theta)$, right?

So the mode should be near to the mean, which is $(1-\theta)n$.
Then, is plausible to expect the mode in some interval of the form $[(1-\theta)n-\alpha, (1-\theta)n+\alpha]$.
If you observe some histogram of the some binomial distribution you will see clearly what I'm saying.

Now, to determine precisely the interval you should determine where the PMF is increasing and decreasing. (Look to some image of the distribution and you will see why this is the way you should proceed)

$$\frac{P(X=k+1)}{P(X=k)}=\frac{(n-k)(1-\theta)}{(k+1)\theta}$$

Now, we must know where this increase. This is solve for $k$ the following inequality

$$\frac{(n-k)(1-\theta)}{(k+1)\theta} \ge 1$$

Which is true for $k\ge n(1-\theta) -\theta$

To the decreasing case you solve for $k$

$$\frac{(n-k)(1-\theta)}{(k+1)\theta} < 1$$

Remembering $k\in \{0,1,2,..,n\}$ you get what you want

$$ n(1-\theta) -\theta \le k \le n(1-\theta) -\theta +1 $$

Comment: Thanks. I think you mixed up the inequalities though. $\frac{(n-k)(1-\theta)}{(k+1){\theta}} >1$. $(n-k)(1-\theta) > (k+1){\theta}$. $n - n{\theta} - k + k{\theta} > k{\theta} + \theta$. $-k > -n + n{\theta} + {\theta}$. $k < n - n{\theta} - \theta$. $k < n(1-\theta) - \theta$

Comment: You are right! I edited my answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the *ratio* $\displaystyle \frac{P\{X=k\}}{P\{X = k-1\}}$ and show that it is an *increasing* function of $k$ for small values of $k$ and a *decreasing* function of $k$ for large values of $k$. For most choices of $p$, the point where
the ratio changes from increasing to decreasing is unique. In some cases, the ratio might have value $1$ for some $K$ (greater than $1$ for smaller values, less than $1$ for larger values) and in this case there are twin peaks at $K-1$ and $K$.

Comment: Read my comment on the question. It may be that you need to delete all the stuff above because you are starting from a wrong formula for $P(x)$.

Comment: I don't really see that it will make much of a difference to the working I've done though?

Comment: OK, whatever. I give up.

Comment: You mean you give up on my stupidity or the question in general :?

Comment: Please look at the edit. It seemed unnecessary to me at first but I think I was wrong